# Converting an array of floats to datetime

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, timedelta

I am struggling to convert an array of floats (numbers with decimal places) to datetime. What I have is a huge array with non-integers (like those produced with Microsoft Excel) that denotes days after a certain date.
If I do it for only 1 float number, say 28.79167, starting for an initial date 01/01/2014, I would do it like below:

```
date = datetime(2014,01,01) + timedelta(days=28.79167)
print date
Out[142]: datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 29, 19, 0, 0, 288000)
```

which looks correct!
But, when I have an array, say the one below:

```
dcc = np.arange(0,10,0.5)
print dcc
array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  5. ,
    5.5,  6. ,  6.5,  7. ,  7.5,  8. ,  8.5,  9. ,  9.5])
```

Then I would do it like:

```
date = [datetime(2014,01,01) + timedelta(days=dcc[i]) for i in dcc]
```

which gives:

```
/usr/bin/ipython:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future #! /usr/bin/python

print date
Out[138]:
[datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 12, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 12, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 2, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 2, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 2, 12, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 2, 12, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 3, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 3, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 3, 12, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 3, 12, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 4, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 4, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 4, 12, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 4, 12, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 5, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 5, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 5, 12, 0),
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 5, 12, 0)]
```

which obviously it's not what I wanted.
Another idea to get integers was to simply convert dates to seconds and then use timedelta like before, but look what happens:

```
date = [datetime(2014,01,01) + timedelta(seconds=dcc[i]*86400) for i in dcc*86400]
```

Note the use of 'seconds' in the timedelta now instead of 'days'. This gives the following:

```
IndexError: index 43200 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 20
```

I tried many web searches, but either nobody else has come up with the same problem or I am making a huge mistake somewhere...

Could anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're miss understanding something, maybe the concept of indexing, here. You need to change `timedelta(days=dcc[i]) for i in dcc` to `timedelta(days=i) for i in dcc`.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! Really silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kasramvd said, your list comprehension is wrong. You are already accessing the items in `dcc`, therefore you do not need the indices anymore.

I get:

```
In [33]: date = [datetime(2014,1,1) + timedelta(days=i) for i in dcc]

In [34]: date
Out[34]:
[datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 12, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 2, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 2, 12, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 3, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 3, 12, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 4, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 4, 12, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 5, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 5, 12, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 6, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 6, 12, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 7, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 7, 12, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 8, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 8, 12, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 9, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 9, 12, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 10, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 10, 12, 0)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time. As I said above, it was a really stupid mistake of mine, which perhaps stems from the fact that I was working really late on a Friday evening... ;-) Regards!!!

Answer (score -1):

try make the datetime first, then add corresponding to each